# c# Conversão hexa

Tags: c#

Preciso criar um array de bytes com o seguinte conteúdo:

```
byte[] arr = new byte { 0x4f, 0x4e };
```

Acontece que tenho a string "ON", onde "O" = 4f em hexa e "N" = 4e

Já tentei armazenar diretamente o valor hexa no array de byte sem o `0x`, mas quando envio para a porta serial dessa forma, não funciona, tem que ser no formato `0x00`.

Como converter a string para um array em hexadecimal?

Comment: Talvez o problema esteja em outro ponto.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar a class `Encoding`, que tem métodos para converter de strings para bytes. No seu caso, por exemplo, você pode usar o `Encoding.ASCII`:

```
byte[] arr = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ON");
```

Comment: Carlos, eu preciso da resposta em hexa. chamando este método eu a tenho em decimal.

Comment: O que você precisa exatamente? Hexadecimal ou decimal é uma forma de representar um valor. Nesse trecho de código acima, o array tem 2 valores, 0x4F (ou 79) e 0x4E (ou 78). Se esses são os bytes que você precisa mandar para a porta serial, então você já tem.

Comment: quando escrevo 79 no array e envio para a serial, não aciona a automação, quando coloco o 0x4f no array, funciona. Preciso converter esta string para o array de bytes, mais populado no formato hexa.

Comment: Como você está enviando o array para a porta serial? As declarações `byte[] arr = new byte[] { 0x4f, 0x4e }` te dá o mesmo resultado que a declaração `byte[] arr = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ON")`. A declaração `byte[] arr = new byte[] { 79, 78 }` também é equivalente à primeira.

Comment: Pois é, mais mandando byte[] arr = new byte[] { 0x4f, 0x4e } funciona.

Comment: Estou usando a classe serial port 
SerialPort com = new SerialPort();
....
com.Write(array, 0, array.Length);

Comment: Dê uma olhada no depurador antes da chamada a `com.Write(array, 0, array.Length)` para olhar o valor do array que está sendo escrito. Todas as alternativas que citei no meu comentário anterior devem gerar o mesmo array.